# C - start traversing from the middle of a string

Tags: c, string

Just double checking because I keep mixing up C and C++ or C# but say that I have a string that I was parsing using strcspn(). It returns the length of the string up until the first delimiter it finds. Using strncpy (is that C++ only or was that available in C also?) I copy the first part of the string somewhere else and have a variable store my position. Let's say strcspn returned 10 (so the delimiter is the 10th character)

Now, my code does some other stuff and eventually I want to keep traversing the string. Do I have to copy the second half of the string and then call strncspn() from the beginning. Can I just make a pointer and point it at the 11th character of my string and pass that to strncspn() (I guess something like char* pos = str[11])? Something else simpler I'm just missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a pointer to a location in the middle of the string and you don't need to copy the second half of the string to do it.

```
char * offset = str + 10;
```

and

```
char * offset = &str[10];
```

mean the same thing and both do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You mean `str[9]` for the 10th char, or `str[10]` for the 11th, but yes you can do that.

Just be careful that you are not accessing beyond the length of the string and beyond the size of memory allocated.

It sounds like you are performing **tokenization**, I would suggest that you can directly use **[`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)** instead, it would be cleaner, and it already handles both of what you want to do (strcspn+strncpy and continue parsing after the delimiter).

Comment: I would, but I need to know which delimiter I used. You can do that with strtok, but since it removes the delimiter, it involves some copying and arithmetic, which granted isn't that hard, so that is always an option.

Answer (score 0):

you can call `strcspn` again with `(str + 11)` as first argument. But make sure that length of `str` is greater than `11`.

```
n = strcspn(str, pattern);
while ((n+1) < strlen(str))
{
    n2 = strcspn((str+n), pattern);
    n += n2;
}
```

Note : using `char *pos = str[11]` is wrong. You should use like `char *pos = str + 11;`